# How can I hide cross tab column when all data is zero?

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

How to hide the column generated by measure (in details section) in cross tab when all the values are 0. Currently am getting a column with zero values. Can anyone point a solution?

**jrxml code**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.0.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.0.0  -->
<!-- 2016-02-23T23:05:34 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="48809477-2290-4dda-a6f9-5d348ff0b70b">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Sample DB"/>
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab 1_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab 1_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab 1_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Style1" isBlankWhenNull="true"/>
    <style name="Crosstab 2_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab 2_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab 2_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab 2_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select 
id,
name,
cost,
0 as new
from product]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="COST" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="NEW" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="352" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="10" y="40" width="299" height="120" uuid="05be91e1-9bd6-407e-8feb-ad21aedcb054"/>
                <rowGroup name="ID1" width="60">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.Integer">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="ed1b3cbe-2a65-4ee8-9882-50b1817b941c"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ID1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="9c778658-e79c-4919-8e40-196b735ce152"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total ID1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="NAME1" height="20">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CH">
                            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="a705ac4c-f769-4b2b-84ae-62965d542558"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{NAME1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="70643653-511b-4b84-8d7c-e0cc09aac39e"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total NAME1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="NEW_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{NEW}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CD">
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="b0423e55-9ba8-4bc8-b032-5773c2e71ce1">
                                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{NEW_MEASURE1}==null?true:false]]></printWhenExpression>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{NEW_MEASURE1}.intValue()==0)?null:$V{NEW_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="NAME1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="df784b91-a1cc-4cd6-b7f8-56a271e0947a"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{NEW_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="ID1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="70e0669b-1684-4cc8-8671-0c29ac37921c"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{NEW_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="ID1" columnTotalGroup="NAME1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="1da6c415-c92a-4624-aae2-59802fe85538"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{NEW_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Edit**: Can not filtering in query since it result in less no of rows. I like to show row even if column value is 0.

Comment: Don't pass it,filter away before?

Comment: I am getting a column with zeros in  crosstab measure.What I want is, I need to suppress the whole column if it is null or zero.I have tried with ($V{NEW_MEASURE1}.intValue()==0)?null:$V{NEW_MEASURE1} in text field expression of measure and used blank when null ..But it leads to a blank column in the position

Comment: Need to see your datasource to understand how?, sql, xml, normally crosstab data is row,col1,20;row,col2,0;row,col3,2; in this case you need to remove row,col2,0 and you do it in query...

Comment: I have added the code and it uses a sample database for testing

Comment: Your example is strange what is 0 as NEW??, where new <> 0...., use sql to remove the line....

Comment: I;ve just given 0 for testing .when all the columns in measure is zero it is showing a column full of zeros,but If I handle zero with null and checked blank when null it is giving a blank column.Same thing when all the fields in measure are null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104323/discussion-between-harun-prasu-and-petter-friberg).

Comment: sorry had to go home... children, you need to use a query to remove the 0...

Comment: What happen with this question? all ok, filtering out data and ok?

Comment: Filtering in query resulting less no of rows .. It is not the desired result.

Comment: hmm, you can't remove in jrxml column after report is created, but I still believe you can do it query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove the entire column in jrxml after the report have been filled, hence what you need means that the report has to be filled first (need to loop all records to see if all is 0).

Your solutions are:

1. Finding the correct query sql with correct filter (where) that allow you to keep the records but not include the value that is generating the column.
2. Using pre query's (in example java) to understand how the final query should be pass this query to jasper report via parameter.
3. Use [dynamic-reports](/questions/tagged/dynamic-reports) or [dynamic-jasper](/questions/tagged/dynamic-jasper), generating the report dynamically first looping datasource to find which columns need to be included.
4. Post elaborate the Jasper Print before export, deleting and moving objects.